# Swift 5 Convert ASCII String to UTF8

Tags: swift, character-encoding, ascii

I'm trying to convert ASCII String from barcode scanner input in UItextfield to UTF8

I tried this

```
let string = string.utf8EncodedString    

extension String {

    func utf8EncodedString()-> String {
        let messageData = self.data(using: .nonLossyASCII)
        let text = String(data: messageData!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "err"
        return text
    }
}
```

Any idea's? Dr Google and I are stumped.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Why would you convert your string to data and back to string ? Note that `data(using: .nonLossyASCII)` might return `nil`. You should never force unwrap the result. It will crash your app if it fails.

Comment: Beyond that: UTF-8 is a strict superset of ASCII, meaning that the first 128 characters in UTF-8 _are_ ASCII — so if you have an ASCII string, it is already a UTF-8 string exactly. You shouldn't need to perform any conversions; what do you see if you leave your original string alone, without attempting any conversions?

Comment: The issue I am having is that I am using a predicate to search for a UUID in CoreData. If I leave the request as ASCII, the predicate returns 0 results, however if I past UTF8 in place of the input the predicate works every time.